# Is it possible to maintain responsive design in WebView for Android native apps?

Tags: java, android, web, webview, native

[image] When I add website in webview, content goes outside of box, website is responsive, any one help with that?

Responsive website should behave same in the webview like we browse website in browser chrome or other browser.

is there anything to setup in webview, so responsive website looks same in webview?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, WebView works as a container, like any other web browser. It only shows the content based on how the view is defined in HTML. If your website has already handled responsive for different browsers, it will work perfectly on WebView as well. Please ensure that the following meta tag is added to the web content:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

In the application side implementation, add some basic WebView settings as below:

```
webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
```

These settings enable the website to adjust its layout to fit the dimensions of the WebView properly.

Comment: I have tried that, not working, same issue